# System.IndexOutOfRange with double[]

Tags: c#

First: This is my first topic, and ask in stackoverflow community, 
Secondly: Sorry for my english, i'm not from England, or any English-talk countries.
Third: Sorry for my "words" ; i'm not very good at writing and explaining anything ;p
So.. i know somthing about programming, but C# is for me 'refresh'.

I just wanted to made a simple function, but it throws me an exception 
**System.IndexOutOfRangeException**

in this Line:

```
        return new Tuple<double, double, double[]>(CarYear[temp2], temp, CarYear);
```

Exacly on the last "CarYear" var;

full function code:

```
    public Tuple<double, double, double[]> determineCarValue(int year, double price)
    {
        double[] CarYear = new double[116];
        int temp2 = (year.ToString() != "") ? year : 0;

        if (year.ToString()[0] == '1')
        {
            int.TryParse(string.Format("{0}{1}", year.ToString()[2], year.ToString()[3]), out temp2);
        }
        else if (year.ToString()[0] == '2')
        {
            int.TryParse(string.Format("{0}{1}", year.ToString()[2], year.ToString()[3]), out temp2);
            temp2 += 100;
        }

        double temp = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < CarYear.Length; i++)
        {
            if(i == temp2)
                temp = ((i / 116.0) * 100.0)  ; 

            CarYear[i] = price * (100 - ((i / 116.0) * 100.0) ) == 0?1: (100 - ((i / 116.0) * 100.0));
        }

        return new Tuple<double, double, double[]>(CarYear[temp2], temp, CarYear);
    }
```

So.. what should I do?

Comment: your problem is most likely the value of `temp2`, run the code in debug and look at the value of `temp2`

Comment: What is `year` value?

Comment: Please ! replace   `int temp2 = (year.ToString() != "") ? year : 0;`  with `int temp2 = year`

Comment: If you have a `CarYear` array with 116 items in it, then passing in a year of 2016 is going to go well beyond the bounds of that array.

Comment: Oh, so fast; wait a sec;

year is a value :               `if (a < 1900) a = 1900;
                if (a > 2016) a = 2016;`

Comment: strange valuation calculation, the input price makes no difference as you have it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
int temp2 = (year.ToString() != "") ? year : 0;
```

You are setting temp2 with a value that could go i guess from 1900 to 2016. But you use that value as an index for an array of 116 values, so of course it would get out of bounds. Change that line for something like this:

```
int temp2 = int.Parse(year.ToString().Substring(1, 3));
```

Basically this way you strip the first digit of the year, so you can use that as the index of your array.

Comment: This mine version works too, but your version is faster *-* ;3

The problem were in ...

CarValue[116] ; i Had to change it to [117] Why? 1900 + 116 = 116 values + 2000 ; and this is 117 values ^^ :D 

Thanks for fast reply, and this nice fix :D